# Regex accent insensitive for short codes

Tags: regex, wordpress, accent-insensitive

I'm working with wordpress' plugin CFDB and I'm trying to filter a name with accents.

Plugin's creator told me it is working with Regex.

The filter is working using mode modifiers (like case insensitive "i"):

```
[cfdb-datatable form="DB" filter="Name~~/.*$_GET(value2filter).*/i"]
```

Now, I want to add a kind of "mode modifier" for accent insensitive. I have tried adding the accents and their unicode translations but it doesn't work on short codes. Any idea?

Comment: Please show some examples of input you want to match, both with and without accented characters.

Comment: @Bohemian I have "José", "Jose" and "jose" in the database. I want to find them using "value2filter=jose". By the moment, it is finding "jose" and "Jose". I'm using á, é, í, ó, ú and ü

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring accents, ie matching `"é"` with `"e"`, can't be done "elegantly" with single unicode point characters. You would have to do something like:

```
/jos[eé]/i
```

To match accent variants of `Jose`, and you would have to build the regex up in your app layer, which wold have to know about all variants for every letter.

However, if your input characters are accented using [diacritic marks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) (separate code points that are "combined" with the preceding character), you could use the posix diacritic mark class `\p{M}`, eg:

```
/jose\p{M}?/i
```

Then you could then just insert `\p{M}?` after every letter (or possibly just every vowel) to create the regex.